# C++ program not compiling with ncurses even though library is installed

Tags: c++, compilation, ncurses

I have been trying to compile a basic ncurses C++ program

```
#include <ncurses.h>
int main ()
{
 initscr();
 printw("Hello");
 refresh();
 getch();
 endwin();
 return 0;
}
```

Upon running the command

```
g++ -o hello hellocurses.cpp -lncurses
```

I get the error

```
hellocurses.cpp:1:10: fatal error: ncurses.h: No such file or directory
1| #include (ncurses.>
 |          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated
```

The ncurses library is installed on my system. The output of `locate libncurses` is shown
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFLWm.png)

What more needs to be done to link the ncurses library to the program?

Comment: You may need `-I/where/you/have/ncurses/directory` as well.  (On my system, it is `-I/usr/local/opt/ncurses/include`.)

Comment: The output from `locate` doesn't show any system files for ncurses development (likely `ncurses.h` isn't present).

Comment: @Eljay I tried doing that by including the libncurses.so under `anaconda3/lib/`. This throws up the same error as before. Then I also included `anaconda3/include/` under which the `ncurses.h` file is present. So the complete command is `g++ -o hello hellocurses.cpp -I/home/tsdd/anaconda3/include/ -I/home/tsdd/anaconda3/lib/ -lncurses` This gives the error `/usr/bin/ld: hellocurses.cpp:(.text+0x1a): undefined reference to 'printw' ` and more errors similar to this containing all the functions used in the program

Comment: Use `-L/home/tsdd/anaconda3/lib/` instead of `-I/home/tsdd/anaconda3/lib/`.